# Objective C iterate over and NSDictionary within an NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to loop over a neatest NSDictionary within a NSDictionary.

currently I have this and this returns the first NSDictionary items

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response

for (NSString *tempObject in json ) {
    NSLog(@"Single element: %@", tempObject);
}
```

The Above works fine

however I wish to read a array layer lower and the blow is failing,

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:kNilOptions error:&error];

for (id tempObject in json ) {
    NSLog(@"Object: %@, Key: %@", [json objectForKey:tempObject], tempObject);
}
```

Thanks Mich

Comment: can you please post the json Dictionary contents ? What does it contain?

Comment: How is it failing? What error do you get?

Comment: The json content is from a API

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to check whether the deserialized object contains ARRAY or DICTIONARY within. You can check the type of object before trying to access it. Something like this.

```
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    for (id jsonObject in json ) {
        NSLog(@"Object: %@, Key: %@", [json objectForKey:tempObject], tempObject);
            if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){

                NSDictionary *deserializedDictionary = jsonObject;
                NSLog(@"Deserialized JSON Dictionary = %@",
                      deserializedDictionary);

            }
            else if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){

                NSArray *deserializedArray = (NSArray *)jsonObject;
                NSLog(@"Deserialized JSON Array = %@", deserializedArray);

            }
            else {
                /* Some other object was returned. We don't know how to 
                 deal with this situation as the deserializer only 
                 returns dictionaries or arrays */
            }
    }
```

Hope it helps you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    for (NSString *tempObject in json ) {
        NSLog(@"Object: %@, Key: %@", [json objectForKey:tempObject], tempObject);

        NSLog(@"Object: %@, Key: %@", [json valueForKey:tempObject], tempObject);
    }
```

//OR by using fast enumeration

```
[json enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"@@@@Key Value is:%@ = %@", key, object);
}];
```

Hope it helps you....!